# How can I convert a string into a tuple in python?

Tags: python, string, integer, tuples

My problem is that I want to convert this type of pieces of string into tuples. But I want the word to be a string and the number to be an integer. Is there some simple solution for this problem?

```
mystring = "(Ilioupoli,2)"
```

The output should be:

```
("Ilioupoli", 2)
```

I've been looking for some solutions but didn't find the solution for this one. I've found solutions to convert string of numbers into tuples with "map" but it doesn't fit well here.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi The answers there only work when the string contains valid Python syntax. It won't work for this because there are no quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `()` around it, use `split()` to split it at the comma, then convert the second element to an integer.

```
mystring = "(Ilioupoli,2)"
fields = mystring.strip("()").split(',')
mytuple = (fields[0], int(fields[1]))
```

Comment: Or `fields = mystring[1:-1].split(',')`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `()` using `.replace()` and split the string using `.split()` at the comma to split the the string into a list, then convert the list into a tuple.

```py
mystring = "(Ilioupoli,2)".replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(",")
tupl = (mystring[0], int(mystring[1]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use string replace to replace the ( and ) with nothing.  Split the string on the ',' using string.split.  Take the first element as a string, and convert the second using int or float.  Then construct your tuple.